# what property to configure in serenity.properties file to Run chrome driver in maven project?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I am using selenium with serenity framework with maven.
Earlier i had placed my chrome driver in resources/Drivers and configured
webdriver.chrome.driver = .\resources\Drivers\chromedriver.exe.
It worked fine for me.
Now i have configured chrome dependency in pom.xml as below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.36.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now this dependency will be in .m2 repository.

I am not getting what should i configure "webdriver.chrome.driver" in serenity.properties.
If i remove this property and run my project i get:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ContextAware

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your property file `webdriver.driver = chrome`.

And you only have to declare your driver as following, serenity will initial it for you:

`@Managed
WebDriver webdriver;`